# using gmail actions in mailchimp templates?

Tags: javascript, gmail, mailchimp, email-templates, google-schemas

I did a google and stackoverflow search but didn't find relevant results. Does anyone know if you can use google's gmail actions api inside mailchimp templates? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find information on how to use this feature here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/

Mailchimp has begun incorporating this feature into Subscription Confirmation emails automatically.  There's no need for you to do anything.

If you would like to add Action buttons to other types of emails you can follow the steps outlined on Google (link above). You must send Google a sample email marked up with structured data, and then [register your sending account with them](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1).

Once registered, you can add Action buttons to your emails using Schema.org style microdata markup and JSON.

---

For example: [(excerpt from Google)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/go-to-action#use_cases)

> Go-To actions are easy to declare. Once you have markup your content
>   with schema.org entities, you may add go-to actions for them. For
>   instance, to make an Event entity have a RsvpAction Go-To link, you
>   just need to populate the event's action property, as in the following
>   example:

Add this in the  of your email:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "John's Birthday Party",
                 ... information about the event ...
        "action": {
            "@type": "RsvpAction",
            "url": "http://events-organizer.com/rsvp?eventId=123",
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is an example of what you would add to the markup

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="John's Birthday Party"/>
        ... information about the event ...
    <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="https://events-organizer.com/rsvp?eventId=123"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Note that Gmail buttons are [not designed to be used in bulk marketing emails](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines).  The purpose of these buttons and the schema's which Google support are designed to be implemented in transactional style emails only.

Comment: I tried to register sending account, but email bounce notification is coming. It seems, link is not active

Comment: "register your sending account with them." from answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to find and ask questions about mailchimp

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mailchimp-api-discuss